# VAR restrictions on Exogenous Variables

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression, restrictions

Technically it should be possible to restrict the coefficient matrix of the exogenous variables by setting the desired restriction = 0, am I right there?
If so, does anyone know how to implement that in R? As far as I know,this isn't embedded in the `var` or `svar` functions of the `vars` package in R.
Thank you.

Comment: Which R package do you have in mind (regarding the `var` and `svar` functions that you mention)?

Comment: Its the "vars" package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vars.pdf